# already accepted android license but flutter android license unknown (Mac)

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

i'm already accept android licenses using sdkmanager but flutter android licenses unknown

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtPGw.png)

[my environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqMcg.png)

Comment: sorry being stupid, this is already fixed by using `sdkmanager --licenses` instead of `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.